# How to auto backup MySql database periodically in winforms?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, database-backups

In winforms application  I want to backup my database once for every week. How can i do this. Can it  be done through Coding or should I go for batch file? And the backup must be done automatically with out any user interface..

Comment: Why not googling for 3 seconds? http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? You could use the `mysqldump` executable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it either way.

If you write a batch file, you can have the Windows Scheduler run this file once a week.

Either way, you must make sure the database is closed before running the backup. This may be easier with code.

Use the `Copy` method of the `System.IO.File` class.